# Print a given number of lines from a text file using PHP

Tags: php, file-io, text-files, user-input

I have a small 10 line max text file that holds a users top 10 favorite songs. I have a form that allows the user to input a number 1-10 and display the top 'X' songs from the file. How can I print out the first 'X' lines of the file where X number given by the user?

Here is my current script:

```
//if topSongs field is NOT empty
if(!empty($_POST['topSongs'])) {

    $showSongs = $_POST['topSongs'];

    if($showSongs <= 10) {

        $allTunes = file_get_contents($tunesFile);

        $tunesArray = explode("\n", $allTunes);

        foreach($tunesArray as $tune) {

            print($tune);

        }

    //if user input IS greater than 10
    } else {

        print(" <strong>A maximum of 10 songs are allowed</strong>");
    }

//if topSongs field IS empty
} else {                                
    print(" <strong>Please enter the number of songs to show</strong>");                        
}
```

the `$showSongs` variable holds the given number to show

Comment: You know, that's what the [file()](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function was created for.

Comment: I've used the file() function ealier in my script. I just didn't paste that part because it is not necessary.

Comment: I think you missed the point. `$tunesArray = explode("\n", file_get_contents($tunesFile));` can be replaced with `$tunesArray = file($tunesFile);` - that's what the file function was created for.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying. Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the foreach for something like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $showSongs; $i++) {
    print($tunesArray[$i]);
}
```

Comment: perfect. Thank you very much. I will accept this answer as Stackoverflow will allow me.