# file_put_contents need to limit number of lines

Tags: file-put-contents

New to php but learning. Getting most help from this forum. I want to see how often my web site gets a visitor and the IP address of the visitor. The following code works flawlessly. The only thing I would like to change is a way to limit the number of lines of data to say...200. Anyone willing to help?

```
$today = date("F j, Y, g:i:s a");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$file_data = "$ip\twas here\t$today\n";
$file_data .= file_get_contents('ip.txt');
file_put_contents('ip.txt', $file_data);
```

Comment: You can see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167008/print-a-given-number-of-lines-from-a-text-file-using-php

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways; here are two and a half.

- Search for up to 200 lines in `$file_data` and output what was found. Replace your last line with:

  ```
  preg_match("/(.*\R){0,200}/", $file_data, $matches);
  file_put_contents("ip.txt", $matches[0]);
  ```
- Read the file into an array and output up to 200 elements therefrom. Replace your last two lines:

  ```
  $file_data = array_merge([$file_data], file("ip.txt"));
  file_put_contents("ip.txt", array_slice($file_data, 0, 200));
  ```

  Just a variant of this where your last three lines are to be replaced:

  ```
  $file_data = file("ip.txt");
  array_unshift($file_data, "$ip\twas here\t$today\n");
  file_put_contents("ip.txt", array_slice($file_data, 0, 200));
  ```